# Carrying incomplete research work from postdoc to assistant professor position

Tags: ethics, authorship, acknowledgement

I am a postdoctoral research fellow and recently I got offer for aP position. I am leaving the postdoc position before the completion of contract. My postdoc supervisor is saying that after joining the aP position whenever I publish the research work, which I started in his lab, should include funds acknowledgment of his lab and that he should be the corresponding author.  
I worked in his lab for just 5 months and I already submitted to SCI journal articles in Q1 level. A week ago I shared my preliminary work which will take another 5-6 months to be ready for submission. In this case I will be spending 90% of time on this topic after leaving postdoc position, why should I add him as corresponding author and why should I add his dictated funding acknowledgment? 
Is it ethical to make such demands?

Comment: You did some work under this funding, so I guess adding the funding is perfectly ethical. Adding him as an author (corresponding or not) is a different thing, which depends (for me) on his involvement in the research published. If you are taking topics with you that he derived, he probably was involved to some extent. If not, that is a different discussion.

Comment: What is the role of corresponding author in your field? In my field it's just the person submitting the paper and organizing the communication between authors and editor/reviewers..

Comment: @Mark In Korea Corresponding author gets extra points in national research funding system.

Answer (score 2):

You should (indeed, I'd say you must) acknowledge any funding that supported any of the research reported in the paper.  If you (like me) are in mathematics, then you should list as co-author(s) whoever made a substantial intellectual contribution to the research.  If you're in some other field then you should follow that field's conventions for co-authorship.

Comment: I am from computer science and the research idea and preliminary results I presented are actually doesn't belongs to any project. It was my independent effort.